# How to iterate through Elements in Jsoup using Scala?

Tags: scala, web-crawler

How to iterate through Elements in Jsoup using Scala?

I am trying to implement extract all links from a webpage but i can't figure out how to do it in Scala.

Comment: i tried making elements into iterator and iterate through it. it works now. Now i wonder how i can just omit links to images. I only want links to html page

Answer (score 1):

After selecting the main div element containing the whole page content, extract all the anchor tags and iterate through each of them and get it's link(href) value.

```
val links = mainElement
                .getElementsByTagName("a")
                .asScala
                .map 
                { 
                    anchorItem =>anchorItem.getAttribute("href") 
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScala` as you will be able to `map`, `foreach`...

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val document = Jsoup.parse(html)
val links = document.select("a").asScala

links.map { 
    link => //logic
}
```